# CSS3 page loading effect trigger by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi friends I am trying to make CSS3 animation which will be trigger by jquery. Ie when the user submit some form I need to display animation (css3) for some duration and redirect it to the next page.

CSS3 animation:

```
.circle {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border: 5px solid rgba(0,183,229,0.9);
    opacity: .9;
    border-right: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-left: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 35px #2187e7;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -moz-animation: spinPulse 1s infinite ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: spinPulse 1s infinite linear;
}

.circle1 {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border: 5px solid rgba(0,183,229,0.9);
    opacity: .9;
    border-left: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-right: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #2187e7;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    -moz-animation: spinoffPulse 1s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: spinoffPulse 1s infinite linear;
}

@-moz-keyframes spinPulse {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(160deg);
        opacity: 0;
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2187e7;
    }

    50% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(145deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(-320deg);
        opacity: 0;
    };
}

@-moz-keyframes spinoffPulse {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    };
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinPulse {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(160deg);
        opacity: 0;
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2187e7;
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(145deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-320deg);
        opacity: 0;
    };
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinoffPulse {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    };
}
```

This is html

```
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle1"></div>
<button class="next" name="submit" id = "submit"></button>
```

Now when I user click on I need to display this effect for a fraction of time (some thing like alert box I mean while this animation is playing user shouldnt  be able to do anything in the rest of the page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you make the page inaccessible by covering it with an element - an "overlay".

*HTML:*

```
<div class="loadingOverlay">
    <div class="circle"></div> <!-- it makes sense to put these inside -->
    <div class="circle1"></div>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.loadingOverlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

To activate it when the user clicks the submit button, just make it "hidden" by default. And when the user clicks the button, make it "visible". In it's most basic form:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function () {
    $loadingOverlay.css('display', 'block');
});
```

and the extra needed *CSS*:

```
.loadingOverlay {
    /* ... */
    display: none;
}
```

On the example I provide below you won't see the animation. The next page, by being blank, just loads too quickly. But you *will* see it on a "real" website situation.

Here's the live example: http://jsfiddle.net/9H7wf/2/

**EDIT:**

Max Boll suggested having the "loading effect" happening on the "new" page. It makes sense. But while a new page is being fetched, the "old" one still remains visible until a few key "http" things happen. See http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2012/12/03/the-perception-of-speed/

So, it does make sense to have it on the "old" page.

Comment: I forgot the css on the example. It's fixed now.

Comment: Not actully like this sir I want to trigger this animation once the button is pressed and  the animation should rum for only 10 sec and I should be able to do any background process in that time . @jopl

Comment: I this case the animation is running for infinite time and also without clicking the button

Comment: oh... yeah. thought you got that part covered. my bad. I'll have my new answer ready in a few moments.

Comment: perfect sir can i keep some time limit to that display thing

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use jQuery for this.

By default you could display your animation as an overlay (as JOPLOmacedo said).

Then you add the following to your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.loadingOverlay').fadeOut();
});
```

This will show the loading overlay as long as the site needs to load (which you actually wanna show by that loading animation). Once the page is loaded, this javascript will fade it out.

My solution is based on JOPLOmacedo's answer.

**EDIT**
I just saw your new comment. To show it on button click, you can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
    $('.loadingOverlay').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Inside of the click event function you could start an interval to fade it out again after X seconds.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9H7wf/4/ isnt working right .. because animation is already running

Answer (score 0):

Hi Friends I found a solution to this one  Thanx @JOPLOmacedo for helping me to fix this one

```
    $function(){

     $('#submit').click(function(){

     $('.loadingOverlay').css('display', 'block');
     function complete() {
         $('.loadingOverlay').css('display', 'none');
      }
            $('.circle').hide().fadeIn(1000,complete);
            $('.cirlce1').hide().fadeIn(1000,complete);
      });

    }
```